# Qt C++ Заголовки таблицы

Tags: c++, qt

Привет всем. Есть **TableWidget** и есть **QStringList** c элементами.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   ui->tableWidget->insertItem(i);
}    

QStringList list;
list << 1 << 2 << 3;
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(true);
```

**Что нужно?** Как сделать так что бы список можно было отмечать чекбоксами. Т.е к примеру я не хочу показывать 2-й столбец заголовка. Мои действия: убрал галочку c элемента номер 2 из списка и показываются в заголовке только 1-й элемент и 3-й.

Answer (score 1):

QTableWidget - наследник QTableView. В QTableView есть метод [setColumnHidden](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#setColumnHidden), который скрывает или показывает колонки по номеру. Генерируете или создаете вручную чекбоксы подвязываете к ним слоты, в которых меняете видимость ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

В Qt это можно реализовать, но не теми инструментами, которые вы выбрали. Для этого потребуется написать собственный класс, наследующий `QAbstractTableModel`. Все данные, которые должны отображаться в таблице, нужно помещать в модель. Способ хранения данных в модели вы должны выбрать сами. Плюс к этому модель должна хранить флаги видимости столбцов (только не путайте с флагами модели, они нужны для определения операций, которые можно производить с той или иной ячейкой). Способ хранения этих флагов - также на ваше усмотрение.

Теперь самое главное. Когда отмечается ваш checkbox, ваша программа должна вызвать метод модели, который менял бы флаги видимости столбцов. В этом методе кроме самого управления флагами нужно вызвать `protected`-методы `beginInsertColumns` и `endInsertColumns`. Например, он может выглядеть так:

```
void MyModel::setColumnVisible(int column, bool visible)
{
    if (visible)
    {
        beginInsertColumns(QModelIndex(), column, column);
        m_visibility[column] = true;  //Ваш массив флагов видимости
        endInsertColumns();
    }
    else
    {
        beginRemoveColumns(QModelIndex(), column, column);
        m_visibility[column] = false;
        endRemoveColumns();
    }
}
```

Соответственно, нужно написать метод `columnCount` с учетом видимости. А в методе `data` учитывать смещение индексов таблицы.

[Полная информация о моделях](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertColumns)

После того, как вы создадите модель, данные можно будет отображать на форме с помощью представления. Для этого используете QTableView. К нему подключайте вашу модель.

Логически правильнее будет реализовать этот функционал с помощью двух моделей: одна будет только хранить данные, а другая - управлять видимостью. Но она будет уже наследовать не `QAbstractTableModel`, а `QAbstractProxyModel`.